# Why NewGlobalRef will core dump on JNI on an IBM JDK?

Tags: ibm-jdk

I believe I have hit a bug on the IBM JDK on its JNI implementation.

I'm working on Apache ActiveMQ Artemis and we recently had to make [this following fix](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/commit/18e41963b61a5ef6dbcdb150e27c07c062deaa66) as we were having issues on the IBM JDK 1.8:

https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/commit/18e41963b61a5ef6dbcdb150e27c07c062deaa66

The issue is around acquiring NewGlobalRef on a methodID, which presumably is an object as well. If you acquire a NewGlobalRef(MethodID) through Sun JDK everything is fine, but if you do it on an IBM JDK, then you would get a GPF.

I could fix Artemis Native layer by removing the NewGlobalRef (as I believe I didn't need in the end), but still the JVM shouldn't core dump because of this.

I have put together a project replicating the issue:
https://github.com/clebertsuconic/simple-JNI-bug

if you revert the last commit, or comment the code around the NewGlobalRef on the method ID everything will pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MethodIds aren't Objects.  There is no reason to get a GlobalRef to them.  Remove the newGlobalRef call and it will work fine on both vms.

I don't know why Oracle doesn't crash (maybe checking the value against the heap range?)

Are you aware of the -Xcheck:jni option? It will help detect and warn about incorrect jni usage.

Comment: Thank you... The Oracle JDK will also fail if you pass -Xcheck:jni. I wasn't aware of this option. will make it part of my surefire parameters so my unit test would catch any future issues.

thank you